# Equals operator not working in sqlite FTS table?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, full-text-search

the fts table:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t_fts USING fts4(p, grp, p_rec, p_time);
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM t_fts WHERE p = ? AND grp IN(?, ?, ?) AND t_fts MATCH ?
```

I get no results but if I run it in SQlite manager I get results like I should.

If I remove the `p = ?` clause then I get results, but more than I need. Why does this happen?

Comment: found the issue. apparently fts don't fully work with prepared statements!! had to put the value instead of `?`..

Comment: FTS *does* work with parameters, but without showing the query in SQLite Manager and your PHP code, nobody can find out what your problem was.

Comment: it doesn't work, try it